# function suddenly stopped working after a simple change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, responsive

Hello good people from stackoverflow.

I got a question.

I recently added a responsive menu to my website. It worked fine. But I added a second, different menu. One made for mobiles. I hide it on a normal scale and show it at the mobile version. But the function suddenly stopped working. No names were changed except for one but that should not interfere with it. Here is the old code:

```
<div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a class="active_page" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">≡</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here is the new code:

```
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a class="active_page" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="header_mobile">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="projects.php">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="icon">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">≡</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And last here is the function:

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0].classList.toggle("responsive");
```

}

It is all linked properly because it worked before. I hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the link to the website, just scaled it to mobile to see it: http://portfoliotristan.esy.es/index.php

Comment: wouldn't you need to target the second 'nav'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[1].classList.toggle("responsive");
}
```

You are selecting the first 'nav' item. You need to select the second nav item by changing 0 to 1.

Comment: Not a problem. If you were to add a class of something like 'nav mobile-nav' to the mobile ul class -- it might help prevent possible issues in the future. Of course you would have to then call 'mobile-nav' -- the first element([0]) in your script

Comment: Yes I see. It makes sense now. Thanks!